# Cant fix a jquery / javascript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code that is picking up some issues in firebug chrome.

any help would be great, please update fiddle.

please see the link with fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwhTd/

image 
[image: jquery problem]

```
    /*  SHOW CATEGORIES
    ===================================================================*/

$('.normal-btn\.interest').click(function(e){
   // Prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('.categories-wrap').fadeIn(); // must be hidden, to fade in
});
$(document, '.normal-btn\.interest').click(function(){
    $('.categories-wrap').fadeOut(); // must be visible, to fade out
});


var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
        $('#profile-container').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#profile-container').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd guess that offset either references many elements, or none.

Comment: jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly what is wrong. `offset` is undefined. You probably expect that it has a value, check why it doesn't have one.

You get more errors though. Something about slider and another about an invalid `.top` access somewhere.

Comment: Im struggling to resolve the bugs here is all the code. http://jsfiddle.net/jwhTd/ can you amend this fiddle please? I would be very grateful?

Comment: No, I can't because the `slider` plugin is missing.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like most of that code is not in the `document.ready`.  the `var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();` needs to be executed once the dom is ready.

Comment: I have updated the jquery code can you update the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jwhTd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;
```

The first line selects all elements with the **class** of `sticky-header`, then gets the offset of the first one. The `.offset()` function returns `undefined` in the event that the selector matches zero elements, which appears to be the case here due to the error you're getting later on.

On the next line you're selecting an element with an **id** of `sticky-header`, which makes me think that perhaps your first line should be

```
var offset = $('#sticky-header').offset();
```

instead, which uses an ID selector rather than a class one.

Comment: I have updated the jquery code can you update the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jwhTd/2/

Comment: @PaulDesigner No, I have no desire to fix your code for you above what I've already done by pointing out a potential error in my answer. There's no HTML in the question so it's simply not possible to fix the jQuery code; it will always fail because the element will never exist. You also need to wrap those parts in a ready handler.